# representing an nD array in DB efficiently

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have some data (currently in CSV format) that is an *n*-D array - there are *n*-dimensions, and one data value for each data point in each *n* dimension. All schema solutions I come up with for storing this array are not space efficient - for example, the obvious solution for 2d:

```
Table ArrayData
----------------
id
row
column
dataValue
```

takes up O(N^2) space, and similarly an nD array takes O(N^N) space. As I know what the size and shape of `row` and `column` are (they are just a range from 0 to whatever) I feel I should only need to store `id` and `dataValue` - the order of the data should be sufficient, akin to how data for an *n*-D array is stored in memory in C.

I could define index-to-array and array-to-index functions - but this seems a little over-kill. Am I missing the obvious? Is there a predefined SQL function for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

We don't think in terms of dimensions for traditional relational database design. We think in terms of objects usually. You could be getting into the weeds a little bit - just because you're storing data in a multidimensional array in your code doesn't mean your database schema should reflect that.

That being said, there are a number of times where it is handy to think in terms of dimensions, specifically OLAP (multidimensional database design). Usually these schemas are built for reporting purposes, to retrieve and aggregate data very quickly from a large amount of data. They're not friendly to query, and they can allow bad data in but they're extremely efficient at what they do.

If I wanted to store a string by 3 dimensions.

```
SOME_VALUE_FACT
----------------
X_DIM_ID int (FK)
Y_DIM_ID int (FK)
Z_DIM_ID int (FK)
THE_STRING_BEING_STORED varchar(200)

X_DIM
--------------
X_DIM_ID int (PK)
X_DIM_VALUE 

(Y, and Z tables are similar)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get your comment about objects and traditional data storage - do you know of other technologies? I'd still like to persist this data as efficiently as possible. The `FK` you describe is `int` and so the storage space is still O(N^N) no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Your choice is to not normalize and leave your values all in one table (duplicating records) or use the foreign key. If the data you're trying to store are actually integers you're not going to save any space by normalizing (which is maybe what you're asking?). If you're only going to be using smaller ints you can try using a smaller datatype (16 bit int?) but you limit your growth quite a bit.